What does the letter/number on the nose wheel door means?
Most airliners have different letters/numbers on the nose door.
What is it for?


Related: Why is there an ETOPS marking on the nosewheel door?

It means that there's a runway incursion and 816 is about to land on top of QT. Roll fire trucks!!!

Easy ID the specific airframe by ground crew.
The whole registration ID is way at the back, likely way up on the tail.
What may be on the nose gear door is just the last few numbers/characters of the full reg num. e.g. Lufthanasa D-AIQT shows "QT" on the gear door  (thanks, jcaron). Enough to identify that particular aircraft, to those who it matters to.

same reason some (many?) airlines place that same code over the cockpit windows, for easy identification.

Not just ground crew, all the crew! I’m a pilot, the reg here is the easiest place to look to look when walking up to a plane to check I’ve got the right one, instead of having to walk round to the back to check the tail. Airplanes are usually parked towards the terminal, so having a reg towards the front makes it easy to check when walking up to the aircraft.

But, if you're wearing your fitness tracker, @tedioustortoise, that journey all. the. way. to the back of the plane gets more steps in! :)

It’s probably worth clarifying that the letters/numbers shown there are a part of the full registration IS (aka tail number), so the Lufthansa aircraft on the bottom is D-AIQT, and shows QT on the nose wheel doors.

@tedioustortoise Are the last 2 characters always unique enough to ensure you never jump into the wrong aircraft?

@EndAnti-SemiticHate yes it’s fine. You will then check the full reg on the flight deck where it is placarded.
